# Re-directing a string containing a git command under double quotes fails

Tags: bash, git

I am creating a bash script-file from an automated bash installation.

That file should only cd into a git directory, look for a new version and if there is one pull latest changes and rebuild.

The script itself works and the file gets created, but on creation it shows me `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` twice.

```
create_file.sh

echo "HOME=/home/nknx" > nknupdate
echo "GOPATH=/home/nknx/go" >> nknupdate
echo "PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH:$GOPATH/bin" >> nknupdate
echo "cd /home/nknx/go/src/github.com/nknorg/nkn" >> nknupdate
echo "git fetch &>/dev/null" >> nknupdate
echo "LOCAL=$(git rev-parse HEAD)" >> nknupdate
echo "UPSTREAM=$(git rev-parse @{u})" >> nknupdate
echo "if [ $LOCAL != $UPSTREAM ]" >> nknupdate
echo "then" >> nknupdate
echo "systemctl stop nkn.service;" >> nknupdate
echo "git merge;" >> nknupdate
echo "make deepclean;" >> nknupdate
echo "make;" >> nknupdate
echo "chown -R nknx:nknx /home/nknx/go;" >> nknupdate
echo "systemctl restart nkn.service;" >> nknupdate
echo "fi" >> nknupdate
```

I ran the script with `bash -x create_file.sh`:

```
 + echo HOME=/home/nknx
 + echo GOPATH=/home/nknx/go
 + echo PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/bin
 + echo 'cd /home/nknx/go/src/github.com/nknorg/nkn'
 + echo 'git fetch &>/dev/null'
++ git rev-parse HEAD
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 + echo LOCAL=
++ git rev-parse '@{u}'
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 + echo UPSTREAM=
 + echo 'if [  !=  ]'
 + echo then
 + echo 'systemctl stop nkn.service;'
 + echo 'git merge;'
 + echo 'make deepclean;'
 + echo 'make;'
 + echo 'chown -R nknx:nknx /home/nknx/go;'
 + echo 'systemctl restart nkn.service;'
 + echo fi
```

Why does it throw this error when I am just creating a file? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Run your script with the -x option : you will see what line(s) trigger the error message : `bash -x nknupdate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As rightly pointed in the other answer, running in debug mode should have help you identify the problem.

The problem is with the command-substitution `$(..)` getting expanded inside `".."` when writing the following commands to the file. The shell has run the commands in the current path instead of appending the command to the file `nknupdate`.

```
echo "LOCAL=$(git rev-parse HEAD)" >> nknupdate
echo "UPSTREAM=$(git rev-parse @{u})" >> nknupdate
```

The shell first tries to expand the quotes which would need to expand the command-substitution i.e. to run the `git` command. Since the path the script runs does not contain a `.git` directory, the above commands rendered a failure.

The way to solve this is to defer expanding the command-substitution, either by escaping it or putting it inside quotes. Either of the approaches should be fine.

```
echo 'PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH:$GOPATH/bin' >> nknupdate
echo 'LOCAL=$(git rev-parse HEAD)' >> nknupdate
echo 'UPSTREAM=$(git rev-parse @{u})' >> nknupdate
echo 'if [ $LOCAL != $UPSTREAM ]' >> nknupdate
```

So, any such lines containing a `$` expansion, be it of variable expansion (`$var`) or a command-substitution `$(..)` should be escaped for the commands to be properly written to the file.

Comment: Works as a charm - thanks for the explanation. Marked this one as accepted answer because it also describes WHY that problem exists. Answer with cat is more elegant and I stuck on this.

Answer (score 3):

For creating a file, there are much more attractive methods than redirecting
every single line. A [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) for example:

```
cat <<'END_CODE' > nkupdate
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

HOME=/home/nknx
GOPATH=/home/nknx/go
PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
cd "$HOME/go/src/github.com/nknorg/nkn"
git fetch &>/dev/null
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
UPSTREAM=$(git rev-parse @{u})

if [ "$LOCAL" != "$UPSTREAM" ]
then
    systemctl stop nkn.service
    git merge
    make deepclean
    make
    chown -R nknx:nknx "$HOME/go"
    systemctl restart nkn.service
fi

END_CODE
```

The single quotes in `<<'END_CODE'` have the effect of single quoting the entire here-doc.

Comment: That's the final solution I stuck with - accepted the other answer because it also describes the cause of this problem. Thanks for your answer!